# Solving $80^{3/2}+y^{3/2}+2\cdot10^8=(y^2+80^2)^{3/4}$ for $y$

Tags: polynomials

> What approach do I have to take to solve this equation for $y$?
>   $$80^{3/2}+y^{3/2}+2\cdot 10^8=(y^2+80^2)^{3/4}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Take whatever approach you like, there won't be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this by getting rid of the constants until near the end, i.e, writing
$$
A + y^{3/2} = (y^2 + B)^{3/4}
$$
where $A = 80^{3/2} + 2 \cdot 10^8$ and $B = 80^2$. That lets me look at the essence of things. Then I'd replace $y$ by $u^2$, i.e., assume that $y$ is positive, so that $y^{3/2}$ is unambiguous. So then I'd have
$$
A + u^3 = (u^4 + B)^{3/4}.
$$
Now I'd raise both sides to the 4th power. That might introduce spurious solutions, so I'll have to check that any solutions I get solve the original equation as well as this one. That gets me
$$
(A + u^3)^4 = (u^4 + B)^3.
$$

THe good news is that when you expand this out, you find that the $u^{12}$ terms cancel. On the left, that leaves terms involving $u^9, u^3, u^3$; on the right, terms involving $u^8, u^4$. In short, you end up with a 9th-degree polynomial.

It's just possible that when you replace the constants, it turns out to factor nicely, but I doubt it. You'll end up having to use numerical methods, alas (i.e., get approximate solutions).

Comment: Following your instructions, I got $$4Au^9-3B^2u^8+6A^2u^6-3Bu^4+4A^3u^3+A^4-B^3=0$$ Another question following this result is, "How do I figure out that there is no real solution and I need to make approximate solutions for a high-degree polynomial?"

Comment: Well...plotting it with Desmos (not very high-precision, I grant you) suggests that the sole root is at $u \approx -464.1$, so there's no (real) $y$ with $y^2 = u$.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side you have 3 numbers, and on the right side only one. I will recommend to transfer one number from the left side to the right side, let say $2\cdot 10^8$. Next step will be squaring of both sides... Try that by yourself...